# OS X El Capitan and Canon mg3600

Tags: macos, mac

I just purchased Canon MG3600 printer/scanner for use on OS X El Capitan.

I am unable to get my Mac to open the install CD for the printer. "No application available".

It will print and copy with scanner controls but not scan to computer. No computer control of scanner.  Any help? thanks

Comment: Are you trying to open the 'setup.exe' file on the CD?

Comment: How are communicating with the printer? Are you using  the USB port or are you connecting wirelessly? Usually, if you first connect using the USB, the drivers install automatically.

Comment: My error It's mg 3620, not 3600. Problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I **NEVER** use the drivers from the supplied media. I **ALWAYS** download the latest from the manufacturers website by googling (in your case) "Canon MG3600 Mac Driver."

Choose the top result that has "canon.com" as the domain (eg not an ad or a site specializing in driver downloads as they often bundle adware with the drivers) and you will (almost always) go right to the page where you can download the latest and greatest driver for your make and model of printer, scanner or any other 3rd party device that requires a driver.

It is possible that you got a Windows only CD or merely a defective disc. Regardless of that download the driver from the manufacturers site to ensure you have the latest and greatest version.

Comment: My error. 3620, not 3600. Problem solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Steve Chambers, downloading the newest drivers is important to ensure that you have the best possible version of the drivers. For example, the MG3600 drivers were updated to ensure compatibility with OS X El Capitan, which may or may not be the case of the drivers on the disc that has likely been sitting in the printer's box for several months (even assuming there are, in fact, Mac drivers on that disc).

It does not appear the MG3600 is sold in the US, so here's a link to drivers that contain many languages including English: http://support-hk.canon-asia.com/contents/HK/EN/0100670801.html

Comment: my error It's 3620, not 3600. Problem solved -thanks